# Animation doesn't look like rendered frames

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, video

[image]

I rendered around 500 frames for my animation. I then opened a different project (Video editing) and
used the frames as an image sequence.

Now to my problem:

My rendered animation looks nothing like the frames in the image sequence.

Inside the Sequencer, they all look fine. Once I render the animation tho, the colors look different.

The one on the left is what I want to achieve and what I see in the viewport, the one on the right is what I get.

The difference may not be too obvious here, but I guarantee that it has way less contrast.

First I thought it might be because I used PNG images and now want to convert them to FFmpeg, but the funny thing is, that the one on the right looks exactly like what I got in the project I rendered the frames in before I added a color balance node in the compositor.

Is there some sort of hidden compositor data inside the individual frames that is not getting applied in the image sequencer animation render? (If I render a single image from the image sequence it looks fine, only in the final animation does is look wrong)

Comment: Alright, this might not be the best answer, but I kinda figured out a way. I just imported the image sequence into DaVinci Resolve and it worked perfectly. If anyone still has an idea on how to fix it inside Blender, consider sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the filmic render option (the default color option in blender). This will modify images/videos you import.

[image]

Here I've loaded in an image with a white background. As you can see it looks darker in the viewport

[image]

But if I change the transform to 'Standard"

[image]

Now the colors are as expected

[image]